# Integrating $\int \frac{x^4+1}{1+x^7}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $$\int [(x^{4}+1)/(1+x^{7})]dx$$ ? I am trying to integrate the expression by writing the expression as $$\int [x^{4}/(1+x^{7})]dx + \int [1/(1+x^{7})]dx$$. Now I can't proceed further. Because for the 1st part if I take $x^{7}$ $=$ $u$. So, then $7x^{6}dx=du$. Now to integrate the 1st part, we can integrate in this way$-$ $$\int [x^{6}/(x^{2})(1+x^{7})]dx$$. Now the integration
of the 1st part will become finally $$\int [1/(7×(u^{2/7})×(1+u))]du$$. But I can't solve further. Also I am facing problem to integrate the 2nd part. So, please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please put something in question titles that helps make it distinct, something specific to that problem, without seeing the rest of the post. You can use math formatting with single `$...$` in a title as long as it's not too huge.

Comment: `\frac{a}{b}` would make your integrands a bit more reader-friendly, and would help clarify what you meant by$$\int [x^{6}/(x^{4})(1+x^{7})]dx$$

Comment: Using partial fraction decomposition is usually the way to go for rational functions.

Comment: Have a look at the [Approach zero's search result](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%20%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Em%7D%7Bx%5En%2B1%7Ddx%24&p=1) You can find the general form of both integrals there.

Comment: If I am not wrong, $$\int \frac{x^4}{1+x^7}\,dx=\frac{x^{5} }{5}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{5}{7};\frac{12}{7};-x^7\right)$$

Comment: [WA shows a result in terms of a hypergeometric function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+%28x%5Em%29%2F%281+%2B+x%5En%29+dx), but that function is defined in terms of a power series defined for $x \in (-1,1)$. If you want to involve the "natural domain" of $\frac{x^4}{1+x^7}$, which is $\mathbb{R}\backslash \left\{-1\right\}$, then I don't know how to consider the case where $x$ is defined everywhere other than that interval of convergence I mentioned... (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) That function can be analytically continued for complex $|z| \geq 1$ excluding the branch cut along the line $z \geq 1$, but I don't have enough experience with that. ಥ_ಥ

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any clever technique that helps much here. The standard way would be to write

$$ 1+x^7 = \prod_{k=0}^6 (x+e^{2k \pi i/7}) = (x+1) \left(x^2+2x\cos \frac{2\pi}{7} +1\right)\left(x^2+2x\cos \frac{4\pi}{7}+1 \right)\left(x^2+2x\cos \frac{6\pi}{7}+1 \right) $$

and proceed by partial fraction decomposition.

It's going to get ugly. [Wolfram Alpha gives a 5-line result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%281%2Bx%5E4%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E7%29%20dx) I don't even want to type out here.